# How to put text in the overlapping portion of a Venn diagram in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, diagrams

Using MS Word 2016, how can I put text into the middle (overlapping) part of the Smartart graphic for a Venn diagram, without making another textbox?

With the current Venn diagram layout, I only get 2 overlapping circles.  I feel like there should be a better, faster solution than simply creating a new text-box and placing it over the Venn diagram.

[image: IMG:]

Placing a text box in front of the diagram won't work, because I sometimes need to resize and move the diagram, as well as make it more complex.  Adding another text box will make the document too cluttered.

Comment: as far as googling goes, there is no "ready-to-go" feature for that. you can play with custom boxes like here http://iconlogic.blogs.com/weblog/2011/08/powerpoint-2010-animating-a-venn-diagram.html

Comment: @aaaaaa: Consider expanding that into an answer.

Comment: @aaaaaa Yes, that's pretty much what I'm looking for.  Consider writing that as an answer.

Comment: @ecube: The image in your question is broken. Do you still have a copy of it that you can re-upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default way to do this in Word.

However, you can import images and something like this would be easy to do in paint. You could also use PowerPoint which is likely the best/easiest option.

Comment: While paint works, I find it's hard to keep the formatting of the text consistent with the rest of the document, not to mention it doesn't look great.  I could probably use powerpoint, though I'd have to experiment with it a bit more to find out.